# Internship: Manager never available

Tags: management, communication, internship

I am currently in an intern position and have been for a few weeks now.

My problem is that I can never get a hold of my manager to get feedback on the work I am doing. He will assign me work and when I ask for him to have a look when I am finished or need clarification he isn't available to talk. I ask him when he is free and always plan in advance but whenever the time we agreed upon comes he is too busy for me.

How do I get my manager to actually make time for me as an Intern?

Comment: Can your manager delegate his supervision of you to someone else?

Answer (score 7):

Use other ways to communicate with him.

Write detailed emails to him, show him what you've done and ask him for feedback.

If you got questions for him, email them to him and make sure to note that without the feedback you'll not be able to complete your assignment.

You could also try to have him agreeing to having [daily stand-up meetings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-up_meeting) with you, they only take 10-15 minutes but the results are very good. You can roughly tell him what you've done, what you're going to do next and you can ask him for clarifications.

If you're stuck on an assignment and you've delivered what you've done and why you're stuck then you can use your time to learn something meanwhile waiting for a response -- but that's another topic.

Comment: Thanks, one of the problems that I have is that he's typically unresponsive via email and IM. I'll try and get a regular meeting going when I see him which could help.